# This code is unreachable trying to skip function

Tags: python

I am trying to get the *type of patient* input to control the specific function to call.
I can get input "1" to work but not "2" or "3". They are unreachable.
I am not sure what to do when someone inputs "2".
It should not execute the call to the first function, but go to the second one but maybe I'm wrong and I don't know how functions work in that case. Dang nabit

```
def calc_inpatient_bill(calc_inpatient_charges):
    days = float(input(f"How many days did this patient stay in the hospital? "))
    rate = float(input(f"What is the daily rate? "))
    meds = float(input(f"What are the charges for medication? "))
    serv = float(input(f"what are the charges for services? "))
    calc_inpatient_charges = (days * rate) + meds + serv
    print(f"Charges incurred by patient: {calc_inpatient_charges:.2f}")
    return False


def calc_outpatient_bill(calc_outpatient_charges):
    meds = float(input(f"What are the charges for medication? "))
    serv = float(input(f"What are the charges for services? "))
    calc_outpatient_charges = meds + serv
    print(f"Charges incurred by patient: {calc_outpatient_charges:.2f}")


def exit(end):
    print()


print(f"What type of patient is this?")
print("         1. Inpatient")
print("         2. Outpatient")
print("         3. Exit")
patient_type = float(input(f"--: "))
if 1:
    calc_inpatient_bill(1)
elif 2:
    calc_outpatient_bill(1)
elif 3:
    exit()
```

So as you can see I am using a `if` and `elif` statement to try and direct what function to use, but it is giving me unreachable or if I type "2" it will run the first function.

Comment: What do you think `if 1` does? The format is `if <a boolean condition>`, so what does `1` mean, when treated as a boolean conditional? And what does `2` mean? And then of course, what does `3` mean?

Comment: `patient_type` should be `int`, not `float`. Also, your conditions should be `if patient_type == 1:`, etc... You have to compare `patient_type` to the available values.

Comment: Also you may want to consider what you are going to do if the user inputs a value that is not 1, 2 or 3. As it stands, even after fixing your conditions, your program is just going to break or do nothing.

Comment: [PEP 636 – Structural Pattern Matching: Tutorial](https://peps.python.org/pep-0636/)

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly Structural Pattern Matching would be complete overkill here, and is just going to cause more confusion considering the errors with a very basic if/else.  It does not offer any sort of performance benefit as you would see with Switch/Case in C/C++, and may actually be slower than using if/elif/else or simple expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your conditions are wrong, fix it this way:

```
if patient_type == 1:
    calc_inpatient_bill(1)
elif patient_type == 2:
    calc_outpatient_bill(1)
elif patient_type == 3:
    exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things are causing your program to break

1. `1` when evaluated as a boolean represents `True`. So `if 1` will always evaluate to `True` and the first if statement will be entered, no matter what number the user types in.
2. the user input is assigned to `patient_type`, but the variable `patient_type` is not used elsewhere in the code. in order to compare what the user typed in to your options `1`, `2`, and `3`, you need to look at what is stored in `patient_type`.
3. (more of an opinion) it would make more sense to cast `patient_type` to an int, since you are comparing to integers `1`, `2`, and `3`. however in python3 comparing an integer and float of the same value does work as you want it to. `int(1) == float(1)` evaluates to `True`, but is somewhat less precise.